# Click() jQuery function not working on a simple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html, click

I'm trying to get a simple `click()` method to work when clicking on a certain div. I've looked at numerous threads but haven't been able to find a solution. Here's my jQuery code:

```js
var $Chart = $('#Chart');
var $TopBlock = $('#TopBlock');

$Chart.hover(function() {
    //Top Block
    $TopBlock.hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $MiddleBlock.fadeTo('fast', .5);
        $BottomBlock.fadeTo('fast', .5);
    });

    $TopBlock.click(function() {
        alert("click handler called");
    });
});
```

And relevant HTML code:

```html
<div id = "Chart">
    <div class = "Block" id = "TopBlock">
        <div class = "Group" id= "Capstone">
            <p>Capstone</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Capstone -->
        <div class = "Competency" id = "CapstoneComp">
            
        </div>
        <!--Expansion-->
        <div class = "Expand" id= "CapstoneExpand">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I included the top hover function because it works on its own. However, when I add in the click function, everything breaks, including the hover function. I tried moving the click function outside of the `$TopBlock` hover, but everything broke also. It should be a simple click function here, I really don't know why this isn't working.

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of relevant material. First time poster here. The problem is that the `click()` function is not firing when I click on my `$TopBlock` div. It is supposed to trigger some JavaScript code that will increase the dimensions of my `#Expansion` div, but I just want the alert to pop up first to ensure that its working.

Comment: So we'd quite like to see your relevant (minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML. Also, the JavaScript that assigns/creates those variables you're using. Also, what's not working, and what is it supposed to do, other than generate an alert?

Comment: We have no idea via your example what $TopBlock is, or what it has been set to.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of relevant material @DavidThomas, I have made edits that should give you more information.

Comment: Did you make sure that you hovered over chart before you attempted to click top block? Binding events inside of other events that may be triggered more than once is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I would suggest taking it out of the hover. Unless you hover over the chart element you will never make the binding for the click. Also are you certain this code is either in an onload handler or placed after the chart and TopBlock elements are rendered on the screen? If not then the bindings will also not happen.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure I like the spaces between the attribute name, equal sign and the values, these may be treated by some user agents as separate boolean attributes. I'd suggest you remove them. 2) As the click event handler is inside the hover event, you would need to hover first before it can be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the:

```
$TopBlock.click(function() {
    alert("click handler called");
});
```

out of the `$Chart.hover...` event. Also, take the `$TopBlock.hover...` out of the `$Chart.hover...` event.

So your code would be:

```
var $Chart = $('#Chart');
var $TopBlock = $('#TopBlock');

//Top Block
$TopBlock.hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $MiddleBlock.fadeTo('fast', .5);
    $BottomBlock.fadeTo('fast', .5);
});

$TopBlock.click(function() {
    alert("click handler called");
});
```

See [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7RUbX/1/)

Comment: Also the `$TopBlock.hover`. You probably don't want to be assigning event handlers inside an event handler. They will be added repeatedly whenever the outer event is triggered.

Comment: It works! I thought I had done this earlier and it wasn't triggering, but I guess something went right this time. Many thanks! Also good to know that nesting event handlers isn't the best idea.

Comment: @user3108571 You are welcome! you'll learn a lot on this site ;-)